# Discard a bad object from Java ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, object, serialization

This question is about Java ObjectInputStream.  If the stream is in a state where I *know* that reading the next object will cause a ClassNotFoundException, is there some way of simply throwing away this object (because I actually don't care about the data), and reading the rest of the information from the stream?

I don't think just ignoring the exception will work, since the API documentation says that if you read an object, and a ClassCastException occurs (which is what would happen in my case), then the stream is left in an indeterminate state.

Comment: Why are you ever potentially reading an object that will result in that exception being thrown? Perhaps you should rethink the way you're going about things.

Answer (score 2):

The stream is in a state you can't recover from. In theory you can read the data, but you would have to have a deep understanding of the format and loading the needed class is likely to be simpler. i.e. If that sounds hard, reading the format is harder.